# Deserialize JSON string into .net Object Nested (Collection) Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I might be being an idiot here, but I have been looking at this for the last hour now and I can't make heads or tails of how to do this.  I find the best way to power through these sorts of things is to let it stew for a while, and in the meantime post a stack overflow question in case someone else had the same question.
Any way, I have a json object that looks like this:

```
 [{
 "wackyId": "wck1",
 "wackyType": "wck2",
 "wackyCnfdc": "wck3",
 "wckyArr": [{
    "fieldName": "Full_Name",
    "fieldValue": "Some Text here",
    "fieldConfidence": "0.3"
 }, {
    "fieldName": "Full_Name",
    "fieldValue": "Some Text here2",
    "fieldConfidence": "0.2"
 }, {
    "fieldName": "Full_Name",
    "fieldValue": "Some Text here3",
    "fieldConfidence": "0.3"
  }]
}]
```

I am trying to convert it into use-able .net objects...

Here is what I have so far

```
public class WckyObj
{
  [JsonProperty("wackyId")]
  public string wackyId{get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("wackyType")]
  public string wackyType{get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("wackyCnfdc")]
  public string wackyCnfdc{get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("fields)]
  public List<multiFields> mutliFields {get; set;}
}

public class multiFields{
  [JsonProperty("fields")]
  public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> multiFields {get;set;}
}
```

right now I am currently getting back a result set with no values???  Not sure what I am missing.  I have probably been staring at it to long.

**EDIT:  Good eye posters.  I should have ran my json through JSON lint first, but I was overconfident in my skillz.  Updated to be more correct**

Comment: First, fix your json

Comment: Use one of the online JSON to C# sites, e.g. http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON Object into C# list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481066/deserializing-json-object-into-c-sharp-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fieldnames matches the JSON names you don't need the attributes. This model should match your JSON:

```
public class WckyObj
{
    public string wackyId {get; set;}
    public string wackyType {get; set;}
    public string wackyCnfdc {get; set;}
    public List<WckyArray> wckyArr {get; set;}
}

public class WckyArray
{
    public string fieldName {get; set;}
    public string fieldValue {get; set;}
    public string fieldConfidence {get; set;}
}
```

Now you should be able to deserialize your JSON via `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WckyObj>>`